# Why does doing \\ in LaTeX causes Undefined control sequence error

Tags: errors, line-breaking

I have a weird LaTeX error here. It seems as if the newline (`\\`) command is the culprit of a compilation error. The error shows up at the ending line of the .tex document: the `\end{document}` line, stating that *this* line has the undefined control sequence.

This code, though, is actually what causes the error.
This will compile (formatted incorrectly):

```
\defn{Method of Moments Estimator (MOME)}{a} 
Properties of MOME:
```

But this won't compile (formatted correctly):

```
\defn{Method of Moments Estimator (MOME)}{a} \\
Properties of MOME:
```

The only difference is the `\\` at the end of the line. I have no idea why this should not work.
For reference, this is the `\defn` command that I made:

```
\newcommand{\defn}[2]{
\tab
\textit{\textbf{Definition }}
\textbf{#1}
\textbf{:}
\text{#2}
}
```

And the `\tab` command:

```
\newcommand{\tab}{\text{    } \text{    } \text{    }}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you to all who contribute.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Both compile for me. (side note, you should use `\hspace` to add horizontal space).